# Loading chunk failed on Local IIS

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core, webpack, angular2-routing

Context: Asp.Net Core, published on Local IIS, webpack.

So i've hosted one of my sites at http://localhost/wanvet. (Local IIS)

For main page (dashboard) everything works as expected.

When i try to get to another component i get a request to http://localhost/dist/0.hash.chunk.js instead of http://localhost/wanvet/dist/0.hash.chunk.js where wanvet is my local iis alias (folder).

Here is the script appending call:

BaseURI being:
[image: Script appending baseURI]

src being the following: 
[image: Src for current chunk script]

And here is the console exception: 
[image: Console exception for chunk loading failed]

I suppose that one way to resolve this is to host the site at http://localhost/ but i'm really not into it.

Successful request for js, css from root:

[image: Request from root]

**Later edit: Added one answer modifying the output publicPath. I still look forward for other opinions.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tested idea is the following.

In webpack.config we can define a appName variable which will represent the alias (folder) that was used in IIS for deploying the application.

And use that when we create the publicPath property.

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var appName = 'wanvet'; // folder name in local IIS
var publicPath = isDevBuild ? '/dist/' : '/' + appName + '/dist/';

module.exports = merge({
    ........
    entry: {
        'main': './Client/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../wwwroot', 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: publicPath
    },
    ........
    }, isDevBuild ? devConfig : prodConfig)
```

Of course you can define publicPath in both dev/prod configs, dev `'/dist/'` and prod `'/appName/dist/'`.